# display all user's choices in receipt

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm new to programming and recently I created a program that should allow the user to select as many items as they want from the menu. Once the user is done, it should display both the total cost and the items they ordered, but it only displays the last item the user chose. The amount is correct and it totals out fine, but it won't display all the items. Here is the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, address, numphone, choice;
    int quantityF1, quantityF2, quantityF3, quantityF4, quantityF5, quantityF6, quantityF7, quantityF8, quantityB1, quantityB2, quantityB3, quantityB4, quantityB5;
    int totalQF1=0, totalQF2=0, totalQF3=0, totalQF4=0, totalQF5=0, totalQF6=0, totalQF7=0, totalQF8=0, totalQB1=0, totalQB2, totalQB3=0, totalQB4=0, totalQB5=0;
    int paymentMethod, quantity;
    float priceF1, priceF2, priceF3, priceF4, priceF5, priceF6, priceF7, priceF8, priceB1, priceB2, priceB3, priceB4, priceB5; 
    float totalF1=0, totalF2=0, totalF3=0, totalF4=0, totalF5=0, totalF6=0, totalF7=0, totalF8=0, totalB1=0, totalB2=0, totalB3=0, totalB4=0, totalB5=0;
    float totalPrice; 
    float total, subtotal, totalPayment;
    char addorder;
    time_t tt;
    struct tm * ti;
    time(&tt);
    ti=localtime(&tt); 
    
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"=========================WELCOME TO ABANG JAGO DELIVERY ORDER========================="<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<"Enter your address: ";
    getline(cin, address);
    cout<<"Enter your number phone: ";
    getline(cin, numphone);
    cout<<"\n\n";
    
    cout<<"***********************************START YOUR ORDER***********************************\n\n";
    cout<<"Hi "<<name<<"!\n\n";
    
    cout<<"What would you like to order?\n\n";
    
    cout<<"-----------------------------------------MENU-----------------------------------------\n\n";
    cout<<"|===============FOOD===============|====RM====|==========BEVERAGE==========|====RM====|\n";
    cout<<"|F1 Fried Chicken - 2 pcs          |  RM11.99 |B1 Sprite                   |  RM4.55  |\n";
    cout<<"|F2 Burger ayam berapi             |  RM12.35 |B2 Coke                     |  RM4.32  |\n";
    cout<<"|F3 Burger daging berasap          |  RM12.35 |B3 Milo                     |  RM7.11  |\n";
    cout<<"|F4 Ais cream pusing               |   RM6.80 |B4 Iced lemon tea           |  RM5.94  |\n";
    cout<<"|F5 Pie                            |   RM3.88 |B5 Mineral water            |  RM1.00  |\n";
    cout<<"|F6 Kentang putar                  |   RM6.48 |                            |          |\n";
    cout<<"|F7 Coleslaw                       |   RM7.41 |                            |          |\n";
    cout<<"|F8 French fries                   |   RM5.67 |                            |          |\n\n\n";
    
    while(addorder!='N')
    {
        cout<<"Enter your choice (one order at a time): ";
        cin>>ws;
        getline(cin,choice);
        cout<<"\n";
    
        if(choice == "F1")
        {
            cout<<"You choose fried chicken - 2 pcs.\n";
            cout<<"Enter how much set do you want: ";
            cin>>quantityF1;
            totalQF1 = totalQF1 + quantityF1;
            priceF1 = 11.99 * totalQF1;
            totalF1 = totalF1 + priceF1;
        }
        else
            if(choice == "F2")
            {
                cout<<"You choose burger ayam berapi.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much burger do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityF2;
                totalQF2 = totalQF2 + quantityF2;
                priceF2 = 12.35 * totalQF2;
                totalF2 = totalF1 + priceF2;

            }
        else
            if(choice == "F3")
            {
                cout<<"You choose burger daging berasap.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much burger do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityF3;
                totalQF3 = totalQF3 + quantityF3;
                priceF3 = 12.35 * totalQF3;
                totalF3 = totalF2 + priceF3;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "F4")
            {
                cout<<"You choose ais cream pusing.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much ais cream do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityF4;
                totalQF4 = totalQF4 + quantityF4;
                priceF4 = 6.80 * totalQF4;
                totalF4 = totalF3 + priceF4;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "F5")
            {
                cout<<"You choose pie.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much pie do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityF5;
                totalQF5 = totalQF5 + quantityF5;
                priceF5 = 3.88 * totalQF5;
                totalF5 = totalF4 + priceF5;    
            }
        else
            if(choice == "F6")
            {
                cout<<"You choose kentang putar.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much kentang putar do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityF6;
                totalQF6 = totalQF6 + quantityF6;
                priceF5 = 6.48 * totalQF6;
                totalF5 = totalF5 + priceF6;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "F7")
            {
                cout<<"You choose coleslaw.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much coleslaw do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityF7;
                totalQF7 = totalQF7 + quantityF7;
                priceF7 = 7.41 * totalQF7;
                totalF7 = totalF6 + priceF7;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "F8")
            {
                cout<<"You choose french fries.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much french fries do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityF8;
                totalQF8 = totalQF8 + quantityF8;
                priceF8 = 5.67 * totalQF8;
                totalF8 = totalF7+ priceF8;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "B1")
            {
                cout<<"You choose sprite.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much sprite do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityB1;
                totalQB1 = totalQB1 + quantityB1;
                priceB1 = 4.55 * totalQB1;
                totalB1 = totalF8 + priceB1;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "B2")
            {
                cout<<"You choose coke.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much coke do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityB2;
                totalQB2 = totalQB2 + quantityB2;
                priceB2 = 4.32 * totalQB2;
                totalB2 = totalB1 + priceB2;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "B3")
            {
                cout<<"You choose milo.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much milo do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityB3;
                totalQB3 = totalQB3 + quantityB3;
                priceB3 = 7.11 * totalQB3;
                totalB3 = totalB2 + priceB3;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "B4")
            {
                cout<<"You choose iced lemon tea.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much iced lemon tea do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityB4;
                totalQB4 = totalQB4 + quantityB4;
                priceB4 = 5.94 * totalQB4;
                totalB4 = totalB3 + priceB4;
            }
        else
            if(choice == "B5")
            {
                cout<<"You choose mineral water.\n";
                cout<<"Enter how much mineral water do you want: ";
                cin>>quantityB5;
                totalQB5 = totalQB5 + quantityB5;
                priceB5 = 1.00 * totalQB5;
                totalB5 = totalB4 + priceB5;
            }
        else
            cout<<"Enter code in the menu only.";
        cout<<"\n\n";
    
        cout<<"Would you like to order anything else? (Y/N): ";
        cin>>ws;
        cin>>addorder;
        cout<<"\n";
        
    totalPrice = totalF1 + totalF2 + totalF3 + totalF4 + totalF5 + totalF6 + totalF7 + totalF8 + totalB1 + totalB2 + totalB3 + totalB4 + totalB5;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Proceed to Checkout. "<<endl;
    cout<<".";
    cout<<"\n.";
    cout<<"\n.";
    cout<<"\n.";
    cout<<"\n."<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------PAYMENT METHOD------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"1) Cash\n";
    cout<<"2) Credit card\n\n";
    cout<<"Choose your payment method (1/2): ";
    cin>>paymentMethod;
    
    if(paymentMethod == 1)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"PAYMENT METHOD: CASH\n";
        subtotal = (totalPrice * 0.10) + totalPrice;
        cout<<"SUBTOTAL = RM"<<subtotal<<endl;
    }
    else
        if(paymentMethod == 2)
        {
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"PAYMENT METHOD: CREDIT CARD\n";
            subtotal = (totalPrice * 0.10) + (totalPrice * 0.02) + totalPrice ;
            cout<<"SUBTOTAL = RM"<<subtotal<<endl;
        }
    
    totalPayment = (subtotal * 0.06) + subtotal + 10;
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"----------------------THANK YOU FOR YOUR ORDER, GENERATING BILL----------------------\n\n";
    for(int a = 1; a < 8; a++)
    {
        sleep(2);
        cout<<"...";
    }
    
    system("cls");
    cout<<"=====================================================\n";
    cout<<"           ABANG JAGO DELIVERY ORDER RECEIPT\n";
    cout<<"=====================================================\n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\tDay, date & time: "<<asctime(ti)<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\tCustomer name: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"\tCustomer address: "<<address<<endl;
    cout<<"\tCustomer number phone: "<<numphone<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\t"<<choice<<endl;           cout<<"\t"<<quantity<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\t"<<totalPrice<<endl;
    cout<<"\tSUBTOTAL = RM"<<subtotal<<endl;
    cout<<"\tDELIVERY CHARGE = RM10"<<endl;
    cout<<"\tTOTAL BILL (incl 6% SST) = RM"<<totalPayment<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"*****************************************************\n";
    cout<<"     Thank You for Your Order, Please Come Again!\n";
    cout<<"*****************************************************\n";
    
}
```

Comment: It is not a problem in your example but `using namespace std` is generally considered bad C++ style because you can get conflicts between symbols from multiple namespaces in larger codebases. Also, there is the [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) library in C++11 onwards. I agree with @Khoyo's comment about arrays or vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's pretty normal, you overwrite `choice` every time the customer makes a new one with `getline(cin,choice);`.

What you may want to look at are arrays, or vectors. It's probably not far ahead in your book/tutorial ;)

You can also look at https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/arrays-part-i/ or https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/